# Batch script: Parsing text gives totally unexpected output, variable value missing

Tags: batch-file, cmd

**The Scenario:**

I am trying to reformat an output of an application ([Wpkg](http://wpkg.org/), command `wpkg.js /query:a`). I am limited to standard commandline tools.

The command output consists of repetitive blocks of software package title and it's parameters, ie.:

```
Mozilla Firefox
    ID:                mozilla-firefox
    Revision:          23.0.1.1
    Reboot:            false
    Execute:           -
    Priority:          100
    Status:            Installed


Mozilla Thunderbird
    ID:                mozilla-thunderbird
    Revision:          17.0.8.1
    Reboot:            false
    Execute:           -
    Priority:          100
    Status:            Installed
```

This makes a long output that is hard to read. I also do not need all the information.

Therefore I am trying, for each block, to collect interesting information in one variable which I would then output in one line, getting result like this:

```
Mozilla Firefox             mozilla-firefox          23.0.1.1     Installed
Mozilla Thunderbird         mozilla-thunderbird      17.0.8.1     Installed
```

**The Problem:**

To achieve that, I began first to parse the output using following code:

```
rem Split all lines into two tokens

@for /f "tokens=1,2" %%G IN ('%WPKG_CMD% /query:a') DO @(

rem With first token, check what to do:
rem I can get known strings (Store, Ignore)
rem or I can get package name (NewLine)

@set WpkgListAll_ToDo=NewLine

@if [%%G]==[ID:]        set WpkgListAll_ToDo=Store
@if [%%G]==[Revision:]  set WpkgListAll_ToDo=Store
@if [%%G]==[Reboot:]    set WpkgListAll_ToDo=Ignore
@if [%%G]==[Execute:]   set WpkgListAll_ToDo=Ignore
@if [%%G]==[Priority:]  set WpkgListAll_ToDo=Ignore
@if [%%G]==[Status:]    set WpkgListAll_ToDo=Store

rem Echo for debug purpose

@echo [%%G][%WpkgListAll_ToDo%]

rem Next follows some unimportant code

)
```

From that code above I would **totally** expect a following debug output:

```
[Mozilla][NewLine]
[Revision:][Store]
[Reboot:][Ignore]
[Execute:][Ignore]
[Priority:][Ignore]
[Status:][Store]
[Mozilla][NewLine]
[ID:][Store]
[Revision:][Store]
[Reboot:][Ignore]
[Execute:][Ignore]
[Priority:][Ignore]
[Status:][Store]
```

What I get though is...:

```
[Mozilla][]
[Revision:][]
[Reboot:][]
[Execute:][]
[Priority:][]
[Status:][]
[Mozilla][]
[ID:][]
[Revision:][]
[Reboot:][]
[Execute:][]
[Priority:][]
[Status:][]
```

...and I've been trying hard to understand why, but I failed.

**The Question:**

Can anyone explain me why the output fails me and what should I do to get it right?

Comment: Edited tags - This is a Windows batch file, not MS-DOS. MS-DOS does not support the FOR /F syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use delayed variable expansion. First, add `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` line at the beginning and `endlocal` at the end of the script. Then change the echo statement to:

```
@echo [%%G][!WpkgListAll_ToDo!]`
```